# How do I pay the Chrome Web Store developer registration fee from an African country other than South Africa?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to pay the $5 fee with my debit card but the postcode only allows one African country(SA). Is there a way around this? I'm from Kenya.

[image: List of allowed countries]

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: SA is not an African country

Comment: @EslamSamehAhmed How can "South Africa" not be an African country, it's literally in the name

Comment: @Plakhoy I was expecting it is Saudi Arabia. Sorry for bad guess.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but I'm from Croatia (a country which is also not listed). My payment was successful when I set USA as my country. I used Revolut disposable virtual card.